# malloc + Automatic Reference Counting?

Tags: objective-c, malloc, automatic-ref-counting

If I use malloc along with Automatic Reference Counting, do I still have to manually free the memory?

```
int a[100];
int *b = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
free(b);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you have to code the call to `free` yourself. However, your pointer may participate in the reference counting system *indirectly* if you put it in an instance of a reference-counted object:

```
@interface MyObj : NSObject {
    int *buf;
}
@end

@implementation MyObj

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        buf = malloc(100*sizeof(int));
    }
}
-(void)dealloc {
    free(buf);
}

@end
```

There is no way around writing that call to `free` - one way or the other, you have to have it in your code.

Comment: So ARC will call dealloc when it removes the instance?

Comment: @stas Well, not directly: ARC will call `[obj release]` - that's its only job. Only when releasing results in ref counting going down to zero, the `[obj dealloc]` is called.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. ARC only applies to Objective-C instances, and does not apply to `malloc()` and `free()`.

Comment: No. ARC only handles Objective-C instances created with `[ClassName alloc]`.

Comment: Sorry, but could you tell me if a struct made by 'Vertex v;' would count as an Objective-C instance?

Comment: No, `Vertex v;` does not do any heap memory allocation. As a local variable, it would be allocated on the stack and automatically discarded when the scope exits. As part of another structure or object, it would be subject to the deallocation rules of the containing object.

Comment: stas: `int[100]` wouldn't be a valid argument to `free()` anyway, since it would be allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Some 'NoCopy' variants of [NSData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata) can be paired with a call to malloc which will free you from having to free anything.

[NSMutableData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutabledata) can be used as somewhat higher-overhead version of calloc which provides the convenience and safety of ARC.

Answer (score 0):

In dealloc add an if not nil and assign to nil for safe.  Dont want to free nil, malloc might be used outside of init etc.

```
@interface MyObj : NSObject {
    int *buf;
}
@end

@implementation MyObj

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        buf = malloc(100*sizeof(int));
    }
}

-(void)dealloc {
    if(buf != null) {
        free(buf);
        buf = null;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't understand why you check if `buf != NULL` in `dealloc`. Shouldn't you instead check if `buf == NULL` after the `malloc` in `init`, and if so, handle that error? Then, there's no need to check if `buf != NULL` in `dealloc`, right? Also, what's the point of setting `buf = NULL` at the end of `dealloc`?  Especially, if `buf` is a private instance variable, wouldn't you have to be doing something pretty weird in your code in order to access `buf` after `dealloc` is called?

Comment: You are right.   The only reason for the if is to avoid calling free(null) to avoid a crash.  Just tested, free(null) does not crash.